# How to change the values stored in String as per the condition

Tags: c#

I try to retrieve the character sizes from the xml file and stored it in a array and after that i need to convert the charsize into two split values string (like if the array of 1 is 25 i need to display it as 15,9 and 22 means 15,7 ) and after the conversion it will be store in another array. I struggle with that logic. anyone please help me.

```
     public static List<string> charSizes(string xmldocpath, string Parentnode)
            {
                List<string> chsizes = new List<string>();
                XmlDocument profiledoc = new XmlDocument();
                profiledoc.Load(xmldocpath);

                XmlNodeList profilelist = profiledoc.SelectNodes(Parentnode);
                foreach (XmlElement element in profilelist)
                {
                    chsizes.Add(element["size"].InnerText);
                }
                return chsizes;
                foreach (string value in chsizes)
                {
                      if (chsizes.Equals("25"))
                {
                    return ("15,9");
                }
                else if(chsizes.Equals("22"))
                {
                    split = 15,9;
                }
                else if(chsizes.Equals("16"))
                {
                    split=9,7;
                }
}
             }
          }
```

Comment: "like if the array of 1 is 25 i need to display it as 15,9 and 22 means 25,7 "...not making too much sense please rephrase

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
            int k = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < firstarray.Count; i++)
            {
                secondarray[k] = firstarray[k].ToString();
                {
                    if (firstarray[k] == "25")
                    {
                        secondarray[k] = "15, 9";
                    }
                    else if (firstarray[k] == "22")
                    {
                        secondarray[k] = "15, 7";
                    }
                    k++;
                }
            }
                return secondarray;

            }
```